# SchemaFactoryConfigurationError when trying to generate the JAXWS

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am trying to access SOAP web service written using C# .NET Framework with a java client application. Therefore in my client program I have added a web service client and gave the WSDL url. When I click next I am getting the following error.

Stack Trace

```
    javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory cannot be created
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:414)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder._newFactory(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:218)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder.newFactory(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:145)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newInstance(SchemaFactory.java:213)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:234)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:94)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(JAXBModelBuilder.java:142)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(WSDLModeler.java:2244)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:191)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:137)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:381)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:198)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:179)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport2.execute(WsImport2.java:835)
    at com.sun.istack.tools.ProtectedTask.execute(ProtectedTask.java:103)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor96.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_05/lib/M%20yWebLib/xercesImpl.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:1: Illegal provider-class name: http\://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.xs.SchemaFactoryImpl
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:245)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.parseLine(ServiceLoader.java:272)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.parse(ServiceLoader.java:307)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$200(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:357)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.access$600(ServiceLoader.java:323)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:396)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:395)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:398)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder$2.run(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:403)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder$2.run(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:399)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:399)
    ... 29 more
```

If you need my XML I can post that as well.
As I am quite new to programming please give me a detailed answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the java client in the default package. Because the WSDL file will create some new packages. Therefore you have to add the web service client to the default package.